# I can't leave the Game Development chat room

Tags: bug, chat

I was briefly in the [Game Development chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) (DO NOT CLICK HERE OR YOU WILL BE TRANSPORTED INTO THE NINTH CIRCLE OF HELL) early today, and although I'd closed the tab, i noticed I was still listed as in that room.

[image: I'm in Game Development]

So I decided to leave. I clicked the little icon and then OK.

[image: Yes, get me out of there!]

Sure enough, I left Game Development...

[image: but not for long!]

But only for a few seconds. Within five seconds, it mysteriously reappeared!

[image: Is this Game Development or a circle of hell?]

For the avoidance of doubt, I left all other chat rooms as well, and successfully. It's only Game Development that I can't leave. I have no other tabs open with chat windows.

Interestingly, sometimes I *can* leave it, or so it would appear - but only as long as I don't click Rejoin Favorite Rooms. If I am stupid enough to do that, I get rejoined to it, even though it is *not* one of my favorite rooms! If I *am* in some of my favorite rooms, then I just get rejoined to Game Development immediately. (Note that some of my favorite rooms are private rooms and I'm not showing them to *all* of you.)

I am using Firefox 26 on Linux (Fedora 20, KDE). Also, to the best of my knowledge, I have not attempted to parse any HTML with regex lately.

Comment: ... you can check-out any time you like, but you can never leave ...

Comment: Do you have the chat room open in any other windows, on any other devices (phone, tablet) etc? I generally experience this issue when I leave a chat room on my PC but my tablet is still in the room - the next time it checks for messages I get rejoined to the room on all devices.

Comment: I don't use chat from _any_ other devices, at all, ever.

Comment: I know mobile chat is bad but you don't need to avoid it so much! :P

Comment: If I don't get out of Game Development chat soon, I am going to start subjecting everyone in there to ---Team Foundation Server--- moderation. And you don't want that...

Comment: you got markdown'd

Comment: From the database, I can indeed see you repeatedly joining this morning - but: I think this is specific to you (it doesn't seem to affect other folk as far as I can tell). Unfortunately I don't have enough data in that table to see where it is coming from - are you *sure* you don't have other browsers etc open? (note: it would also need them to be glitching - normally if you leave from anywhere, all connected clients as "you" will follow the same action)

Comment: Hmm. I closed Firefox, but found a hung Firefox process that wouldn't respond to anything but `kill -9`. We'll see if that helps...

Comment: Well, Firefox is definitely acting strangely today. Now I don't seem to be in Game Development, but I can't rejoin favorite rooms at all, so I can't really be sure! Whatever the issue is, it's clearly with this local browser, and I suppose you all can downvote me into oblivion now.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've also just kicked our web-socket server in case that was part of the problem

Comment: Oh, well _that's_ why I couldn't rejoin favorite rooms. I can now. No sign of Game Development, so ... problem solved?

Comment: It's pretty common to still be in rooms (or have them reappear once or twice) after leaving.  *Leave* doesn't work very well on SE chat.

Answer (score 10):

This appears to have been caused by Firefox misbehaving.

While I had quit Firefox, I discovered a still-running Firefox process with no associated window which I had to resort to `kill -9` to get rid of. Once I did so, SE chat is behaving normally again.

Comment: as is so frequently the case, the age-old advice of "have you tried rebooting your computer?" would have worked wonders here ;p